# Spring MVC - loading data from database

Tags: spring

I have two entities which are in many to many relation and I can't load `Set <Category> categories`. These fields are filled in the database.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Product")
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int idProduct;
    private String status;
    private String name;
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy= "products")
    private Set <Category> categories;
    }


@Entity
@Table(name="Category")
public class Category {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int idCategory;
    private String name;
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set <Product> products;
}
```

This returns nothing int the view and the loop doesn't rotate even once.

```
<c:forEach items="${product.categories}" var="items">
                            <p>${items.name}</p>
                            </c:forEach>
```

I join the schema. Could someone write what to do to make it work, please?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7sDf.png)

This not works.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Category")
public class Category {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int idCategory;
    private String name;
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "Product_Category", joinColumns = { 
            @JoinColumn(name = "Category_idCategory", nullable = false, updatable = false) }, 
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "Product_idProduct", 
                    nullable = false, updatable = false) })

    private Set <Product> product;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate infers the sql that it needs to create from the annotation on the objects. Your product entity is telling hibernate to get information about the SQL join from the Category entity. This is from the `mappedBy` clause in the `@ManyToMany` annotation.

When it goes to the Category entity, it doesn't find what it needs, and it just gives an empty set.

Most `@ManyToMany` annotations are done with a join table. Here is a sample join table annotation

```
@JoinTable(name = "product_to_category", joinColumns = { 
        @JoinColumn(name = "category_id", nullable = false, updatable = false) }, 
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "product_id", 
                nullable = false, updatable = false) })
```

Depending on your schema, you might need to adjust the above annotation to get it working. It will give you a good start.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Could you tell me what shoud I exactly do?

Comment: Copy the above annotation into your code onto the category entity's Set<Product>. Then change the `@JoinTable`'s name to reflect the table name. In the `@JoinColumns`, change the name field to reflect the name of the columns in the join table.

Comment: According to your schema diagram the join table is called `product_has_category` not `product_category`.